# Can I use custom variables when conditionally calling an Ansible role?

Tags: ansible

As per ansible documentation [here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_conditionals.html#applying-when-to-roles-and-includes) I am using the below syntax to trigger a role when the variable "mdb_user" starts with prod.

```
- hosts: category_workstation
  gather_facts: False
  name: common workstation applications
  roles:
    - apps_workstation
    - { role: apps_workstation_production, when: mdb_user.startswith('prod') }
```

This works nicely but what i want to know is if i can do something similar to adjust the variables fed to the role in different conditions. For instance the below:

```
- hosts : category_workstation
  name: common workstation applications
  roles:
    - apps_workstation
    - { role: apps_workstation_production, vars={'user':'prod'}, when: mdb_user.startswith('prod')}
```

Currently I am having to use when and set_fact to get the right variables setup before caling a roles and this approach above (if possible) seems more concise.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
- hosts : category_workstation
  name: common workstation applications
  roles:
    - apps_workstation
    - { role: apps_workstation_production, user: prod, when: mdb_user.startswith('prod')}
```